# How to make pagination from inline buttons Telegram in Golang

Tags: go, pagination, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using the library https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api

But I do not understand how I can implement the output of buttons and arrows. A lot of data with pagination comes from my api, but I don't understand how to make pages in telegrams. If someone gives an example, I will be very grateful!

This is perfectly implemented in python: https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot-pagination/

But i need for Golang :(

Answer (score 1):

As I checked there were no plugins or wrappers for [telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api) package, so you're gonna have to handle this manually.

- Suppose we have this data:

```golang
var data = []string{"DummyData1", "DummyData2", "DummyData3", "DummyData4", "DummyData5", "DummyData6", "DummyData7", "DummyData8", "DummyData9", "DummyData10"}
```

- If we're going to show 2 items on each page for 10 items, we would have 5 pages:

```golang
var count = 2
var maxPages = len(data) / count // = 5
```

- First we should have a function that calculates data slice and gives us the `inlineKeyboardMarkup`:

```golang
func DummyDataTextMarkup(currentPage, count int) (text string, markup tgbotapi.InlineKeyboardMarkup) {
    text = strings.Join(data[currentPage*count:currentPage*count+count], "\n")

    var rows []tgbotapi.InlineKeyboardButton
    if currentPage > 0 {
        rows = append(rows, tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("Previous", fmt.Sprintf("pager:prev:%d:%d", currentPage, count)))
    }
    if currentPage < maxPages-1 {
        rows = append(rows, tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("Next", fmt.Sprintf("pager:next:%d:%d", currentPage, count)))
    }

    markup = tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardMarkup(rows)
    return
}
```

- Then there is going to be a function to send/edit the calculated data and keyboard by passing `chatId`, `currentPage`, `count` and `messageId`:

```golang
func SendDummyData(chatId int64, currentPage, count int, messageId *int) {
    text, keyboard := DummyDataTextMarkup(currentPage, count)

    var cfg tgbotapi.Chattable
    if messageId == nil {
        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(chatId, text)
        msg.ReplyMarkup = keyboard
        cfg = msg
    } else {
        msg := tgbotapi.NewEditMessageText(chatId, *messageId, text)
        msg.ReplyMarkup = &keyboard
        cfg = msg
    }

    bot.Send(cfg)
}
```

(Note: If we pass a `messageId` to this function it's going to edit our message with new data)

- The next step is to have a `CallbackQueryHandler` to handle a user's click on inline buttons:

```golang
func CallbackQueryHandler(query *tgbotapi.CallbackQuery) {
    split := strings.Split(query.Data, ":")
    if split[0] == "pager" {
        HandleNavigationCallbackQuery(query.Message.MessageID, split[1:]...)
        return
    }
}

func HandleNavigationCallbackQuery(messageId int, data ...string) {
    pagerType := data[0]
    currentPage, _ := strconv.Atoi(data[1])
    itemsPerPage, _ := strconv.Atoi(data[2])

    if pagerType == "next" {
        nextPage := currentPage + 1
        if nextPage < maxPages {
            SendDummyData(chatId, nextPage, itemsPerPage, &messageId)
        }
    }
    if pagerType == "prev" {
        previousPage := currentPage - 1
        if previousPage >= 0 {
            SendDummyData(chatId, previousPage, itemsPerPage, &messageId)
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: The first function `CallbackQueryHandler` is a global callback handler that calls our desired callbackhandler by splitting its query with `:` and getting the handler's name, here it is `pager` as we have defined and its handler is called `HandleNavigationCallbackQuery`).

- The last step would be to call `CallbackQueryHandler` in your update loop as well as sending the initial data to your desired chat:

```golang
var chatId = int64(0) // <--- Place Chat Id Here

SendDummyData(chatId, 0, 2, nil) // Send initial data

for update := range updates {
    if update.CallbackQuery != nil {
        CallbackQueryHandler(update.CallbackQuery)
        continue
    }
}
```

You can check the full example on my GitHub's gist [here](https://gist.github.com/aliforever/298c99efc093b4de8feb25028f49cc54)

Comment: Bro, thanks for the help. I am very glad that there was a person who could help with this. Can you give your contacts? I want to ask a few questions, if you don't mind. Thanks!